# certificate warning on meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com (on firefox)

Tags: bug

Coming to meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com I am greeted with a "invalid certificate" warning:

[image: certificate warning]

Apparently the certificate is valid for `*.stackexchange.com`, but not for `*.*.stackexchange.com`:
[image: certificate details]

At least that's what I understand from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/what-certificates-are-needed-for-multi-level-subdomains). Shouldn't something be done about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe a fix for that is coming any time soon.

According to the SSL certificate standards, only the leftmost component in a certificate can be a wildcard, and the wildcard will not match a "`.`".

In other words:

- `*.stackexchange.com` will match `bicycles.stackexchange.com` and not `meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com`.
- `*.*.stackexchange.com` would not be a valid cert. (or might only work in some browsers)
- `meta.*.stackexchange.com` would not be a valid cert. (or might only work in some browsers)

And, of course, getting a separate "subject alt name" cert for all 115 site metas and redoing the certificate every time a new site is added to the network is too much work to be practical.

More details from one of the Stack Exchange infrastructure people here: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/